# How to add line break in CSS changing text animation?

Tags: html, css, squarespace

I am building website using squarespace and adding custom CSS to replicate the design with text changing animation that would change the text every 3 seconds. The text content is broken into two lines and scaled to fit the text box.

I have code block in which I have added html header h2.

```
<h2 style="text-align:center; font-size:48px" class="animated-text">
  <span style="display:block;"></span>
</h2>
```

Custom CSS

```
.animated-text {
  h2 {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
  span::before {
    content: "Every body is different, and every workout is unique";
    animation: animate infinite 5s;
  }
  @keyframes animate {
    0% {
      content: "Every body is different, and every workout is unique";
    }
    50% {
      content: "Evidence-based, and fitness trainer reviewed Affordable, accessible, intentional"
    }
  }
}
```

Attached are the screenshot of the design which I am trying to implement

[Actual Design - Text block 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtCpC.png)

[Actual Design - Text block 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRdsd.png)

However, my actual result is not exact as I am trying to wrap the text to fit the text block. Is it possible to add line break in text content in span animation content or what would be the best way to replicate the design?

Thank You!

[Actual result - Text block 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXcR4.png)

[Actual result - Text block 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRBqt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
.animated-text {
  h2 {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
  span::before {
     content: "Every body is different, \a and every workout is 
     unique";
     white-space: pre; /* this is important */
    animation: animate infinite 5s;
  }
  @keyframes animate {
    0% {
      content: "Every body is different, \a and every workout is unique";
    }
    50% {
      content: "Evidence-based, and fitness trainer reviewed \a Affordable, accessible, intentional"
    }
  }
}
```

**add line breaks using CSS**

```
  content: "paragraph 1 \a paragraph 2"; /* \a is new line character */
  white-space: pre;
```

Comment: Thank you @Vinod Liyanage. Is it possible to scale text that can remove the white space from line 1 or 2 depending on the text fit.

If you compare both of these you can see what i mean
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRdsd.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gYQJ.png

Comment: the way to do that is by using two span tags. the first span shows the first paragraph and the second span show the second paragraph. this way you can style both of them separately.